# Python: How to call a function within a function and insert a list as a parameter for both functions

Tags: python, function

This is pseudo code just to try explain what I am trying to do simply.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def func_1(x):
    a = ...
    b = ...
    if a == 2 and b == 5:
        do this to the list...


def func_2(x):
    if a == 6 and b == 2:
        do this to the list...
```

This is pseudo code just to try explain what I am trying to do simply.

I want to be able to either...

a) run both separate ifs in one function, but to treat them separately

b) have separate functions but have values for a and b carried from the first function to the other (or the adjusted list at the end of the first function taken as the parameter for the second function)

When I call...

```
x = func_1(x)
x = func_2(x)
```

it says...

```
<function func_1 at 0x244384>
```

it also does the same when I put it all into one function :(

Below is the working (or in this case not working) code. WARNING it is very long. There are probably easier ways to achieve what I want in Deploy_Destroyer_2 but unless this is what the problem is I'm not bothered about advice on this.

```
def InitBoards():
    Player = [[1]*(6 if x<6 else 12) for x in range(12)]
    Opponent = [[0]*(6 if x<6 else 12) for x in range(12)]

    return Player,Opponent

def Deploy_Destroyer_1(Player):
    rand_col_1 = randint(0,11)
    if rand_col_1 < 6:
        rand_row_1 = randint(0,11)
        return rand_col_1
        return rand_col_2
    else:
        rand_row_1 = randint(6,11)
        return rand_col_1
        return rand_row_1
    if Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] == 2:
        Deploy_Destroyer_1(Player)


def Deploy_Destroyer_2(Player):
    if rand_col_1 == 5 and rand_row_1 == 6:
        #can be 1, 2, 3 or 4... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,4)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 in range(1,4) and rand_row_1 in range(1,10):
        #can be any 1, 2, 3 or 4... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,4)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 in range(5,10) and rand_row_1 in range(7,10):
        #can be any 1, 2, 3 or 4... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,4)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 == 0 and rand_row_1 == 0:
        #can be any 1, 2, 3 or 4... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,4)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif (rand_col_1 == 5 and rand_row_1 == 0) or (rand_col_1 == 11 and rand_row_1 ==6):
        #can be one or four
        #check brackets and booleans here
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,2)
        if rand_position_1 == 1: #position 1
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 == 0 and rand_row_1 == 11:
        #can be 2 or 3
        rand_position_1 = randint(2,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3: #position 3
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 == 11 and rand_row_1 == 11:
        #can be 2 or 4
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,2)
        if rand_position_1 == 1: #position 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif (rand_row_1 == 0 and rand_col_1 in range(1,4)) or (rand_row_1 == 6 and rand_col_1 in range(6,10)):
        #can be 1, 3 or 4
        #check brackets and booleans here
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 1: #position 1
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 3
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif (rand_col_1 == 5 and rand_row_1 in range(1,5)) or (rand_col_1 == 11 and rand_row_1 in range(7,10)):
        #can be 1, 2 or 4
        #check brackets and booleans here
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 1: #position 1
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 == 0 and rand_row_1 in range(1,10):
        #can be 1, 2 or 3... in that order below
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 1:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 + 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 2:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3:
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
    elif rand_col_1 in range(1,10) and rand_row_1 == 11:
        #can be 2, 3 or 4
        rand_position_1 = randint(1,3)
        if rand_position_1 == 2: #position 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1 - 1][rand_col_1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 3: #position 3
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 + 1] = 2
        if rand_position_1 == 4: #position 4
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1] = 2
            Player[rand_row_1][rand_col_1 - 1] = 2
    return Player


Player, Opponent = InitBoards()
Player = Deploy_Destroyer_1
Player = Deploy_Destroyer_2

print Player
print Opponent
```

Anybody got any ideas? Or what the above error means?

Comment: What do you mean by "treat them seperately"? Why can't you just put it all in one function?

Comment: To your second question - you need to call the functions! `x = func_1()`.

Comment: have edited the question, sorry I don't know how else to explain it unless someone asks what else they need from me

Comment: post working code, not psudo-code

Comment: And in you edits it looks like your function don't explicitly return which means they return None, so you are blowing away your list by assigning `None` to `x`

Comment: Are `a` and `b` functions of x?

Comment: And in your last edit, you're still not calling the functions, nor passing in the list as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Lists are mutable objects, so the answer is "just do it". It'll work like magic (while in most cases, it's a pitfall).

And I should've looked more at the details, to get *also* a and b into the 2nd function's scope, one of many possible solutions would be:

```
def f1(l):
    …
    return l, a, b

def f2(l, a, b):
    …

f2(*f1(x))
```

Can't propose a fitting solution if we're just talking in f1, f2, a, and b, instead of problem domains. ;)

Comment: This answer is as cryptic as the question.

Comment: I tried this yet it just gave me an error saying that only one argument had been provided for Deploy_Destroyer_2 when it was asking for three @jhermann

Comment: Then you left out the '*'.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def f(x):
    a = ...
    b = ...
    if a == 2 and b == 5:
        # do this to the list...
        pass

    if a == 6 and b == 2:
        # do this to the list...
        pass

    return x

x = f(x)
```

?

(on a side note, the above is legal Python 3.x, as `...` is an inbuilt object!)

Comment: `...` is not a builtin object outside a slice expression in python 2.7

Comment: I'm not sure that this would make sense (I may be wrong, take a look at the working code I've given and the conditions for the ifs. I want it to check against one set of 'if's first, then the next set) @user2387370